# Data SYNC between SQL Server and Mongo DB

Tags: .net, sql-server, mongodb

My application has SQL Server as data base and has huge amount of data. We decided to use Mongo DB for some part. 
So Mongo DB will have subset of data from SQL server DB. And there should be a synchronization process between Mongo DB to SQL DB. The synchronization process will run automatically.

In this context i'm looking for best practices (if any)  for approaching above requirement.
Is there any built-in component for data transfer between Mongo DB and SQL.

Comment: So you want to duplicate some data on both DBs because the data retrieval from mongo is faster?

Comment: There's no built-in component for the data transfer. The structure of the data may be very different between MongoDB and a relational database and the structure in MongoDB depends greatly on the application. First figure out how you will store the data in MongoDB and what the synchronization requirements will be in terms of tolerance for stale data.Then you should write some script to do the data transformation and loading periodically.